# Ico Contract Address Transfer About

Tags: addresses, ico

I'm using this contract code and want to create ico contract. But when I create contract code and try to transfer eth I'm getting error. I can't transfer ethereum to ico contract address.

**Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad jump destination]**

can you help me ?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

import "./ABCToken.sol";
import "./SafeMath.sol";

ABCToken public ABCToken;

// Address of the founder of ABC.
address public founder = 0x3311111111111111111111111111111111111133;

// Address where all tokens created during ICO stage initially allocated
address public allocationAddress = 0x2111111111111111111111111111111111111111;

// Start date of the ICO
uint public startDate = 1524528001;  

// End date of the ICO
uint public endDate = 1535068801;  

// Token price without discount during the ICO stage
uint public baseTokenPrice = 10000000; // 0.001 ETH, considering 8 decimal places

// Number of tokens distributed to investors
uint public tokensDistributed = 0;

/*
 *  Modifiers
 */
modifier onlyFounder() {
    // Only founder is allowed to do this action.
    if (msg.sender != founder) {
        throw;
    }
    _;
}

modifier minInvestment(uint investment) {
    // User has to send at least the ether value of one token.
    if (investment < baseTokenPrice) {
        throw;
    }
    _;
}

/// @dev Returns current bonus
function getCurrentBonus()
    public
    constant
    returns (uint)
{
    return getBonus(now);
}

/// @dev Returns bonus for the specific moment
/// @param timestamp Time of investment (in seconds)
function getBonus(uint timestamp)
    public
    constant
    returns (uint)
{   
    if (timestamp > endDate) {
        throw;
    }

    if (startDate > timestamp) {
        return 1499;  // 49.9%
    }

    uint icoDuration = timestamp - startDate;
    if (icoDuration >= 16 days) {
        return 1000;  // 0%
    } else if (icoDuration >= 9 days) {
        return 1125;  // 12.5%
    } else if (icoDuration >= 2 days) {
        return 1250;  // 25%
    } else {
        return 1499;  // 49.9%
    }
}

function calculateTokens(uint investment, uint timestamp)
    public
    constant
    returns (uint)
{
    // calculate discountedPrice
    uint discountedPrice = div(mul(baseTokenPrice, 1000), getBonus(timestamp));

    // Token count is rounded down. Sent ETH should be multiples of baseTokenPrice.
    return div(investment, discountedPrice);
}


/// @dev Issues tokens for users who made BTC purchases.
/// @param beneficiary Address the tokens will be issued to.
/// @param investment Invested amount in Wei
/// @param timestamp Time of investment (in seconds)
function fixInvestment(address beneficiary, uint investment, uint timestamp)
    external
    onlyFounder
    minInvestment(investment)
    returns (uint)
{   

    // Calculate number of tokens to mint
    uint tokenCount = calculateTokens(investment, timestamp);

    // Update fund's and user's balance and total supply of tokens.
    tokensDistributed = add(tokensDistributed, tokenCount);

    // Distribute tokens.
    if (!ABCToken.transferFrom(allocationAddress, beneficiary, tokenCount)) {
        // Tokens could not be issued.
        throw;
    }

    return tokenCount;
}

/// @dev Contract constructor
function ABCICO(address tokenAddress, address founderAddress) {
    // Set token address
    ABCToken = ABCToken(tokenAddress);

    // Set founder address
    founder = founderAddress;
}

/// @dev Fallback function
function () payable {
    throw;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that your only function marked as `payable`, the fallback function, `throw`s, thus rejecting the eth transfer.

Have a look at this [`Register` contract](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html) from the official documentation and see a nice example, with a brief explanation of how to use the `payable` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I changed fallback function and solved problem but now Ico contract can't transfer me token. Contract is taking ethereum bot didn't transfer token.

IcoDuration is working I'm in +2 days period.